# Determining the differential of a map defined on a submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $M=\{(x,y,z,w)\in \Bbb R^4:x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=1\}$ and consider the function $f:M\to \Bbb R^2$ defined by $f(x,y,z,w)=(x+y+z+w,w^3+w)$. It is easily checked that $1$ is a regular value of the function $g:\Bbb R^4\to \Bbb R$, $(x,y,z,w)\mapsto x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz$, so $M$ is a regular submanifold of $\Bbb R^4$, of dimension $3$. I am trying to determine the differential $f_*:T_p(M)\to T_{F(p)}\Bbb R^2$ at a point $p=(x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0)\in M$. I have shown that tangent space $T_pM \subset T_p\Bbb R^4=\Bbb R^4$ is precisely the set $\{v\in \Bbb R^4: \text{grad}g(p)\cdot v=0\}$. But then how do I have to compute the differential of $f$ at $p$?

Comment: If $F : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$ is $F(x,y,z,w) = (x+y+z+w,w^3+w)$ you mean $T_pM$ is $\{ v \in \mathbb{R^4} \mid \text{grad }F(p) \cdot v = 0 \}$ right ?

Comment: @Eumenes I have made a mistake. I edited it.

Comment: I am puzzled by the question. Since your map $f$ is actually the restriction to $M$ of a globally defined map on $\Bbb R^4$, the obvious answer is that $f_*\colon T_pM\to \Bbb R^2$ is just the restriction of the derivative map $\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^2$ to the subspace $T_pM$. Unless you want to compute in a coordinate chart (and no one really does), this is how you compute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

$1).\ $ Fix $(x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0)\in M$, and find a slice chart $(\varphi, U)$ for $M$ about $(x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0)$. Try letting $F(x,y,z,w)=x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz-1$ and taking $\varphi=(F,y,z,w).$

$2).\ $Now check that

$$\begin{pmatrix}
F_x &F_y  &F_z  &F_w \\ 
 0&1  &0  &0 \\ 
 0&  0&1  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
3x^2-3yz&3y^2-3xz  &3z^2-3xy  &0 \\ 
 0&1  &0  &0 \\ 
 0&  0&1  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

is nonsingular at $(x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0).$

$3).\ $ Find the matrix representation of $f_*$ by using the standard coordinates $(\psi, V)$ on $\mathbb R^2$ about $f(x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0)$, and computing the Jacobian matrix of $\psi\circ f\circ \varphi^{-1}$ at $\varphi(x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0)$.

Comment: Thanks. I did 1, 2 and 3. Then is the differential of $f$ given by the right three columns of the Jacobian matrix of $\psi \circ f\circ \varphi^{-1}$?

Comment: But it is the matrix representation of $f_*:T_p\Bbb R^4\to T_p\Bbb R^2$, not $T_pM\to T_p\Bbb R^2$, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry. Using the chart  $(\varphi,U)$ by construction if $\vec x=(x,y,z,w)\in M,$ then $\varphi (\vec x)=(0,y,z,w)$